# MSChart line chart label overlapping

Tags: scale, point, mschart

i have this problem... the point's label do this:

[image]

the chart must appear prettiest possible, the X Axis of the series will grow up always, but I'm afraid that if it gets more points it'll look uglier.

the chart has 11 points in the image, i tried to scale the X axis to 5  but nothing.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you put the code that fills the series

Answer (score 0):

Try adding smart labels to your series, this will allow you to set some rules so that the display of the point labels without overlapping

```
chart1.Series["Default"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
chart1.Series["Default"].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Partial;
chart1.Series["Default"].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineAnchorCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.Diamond;
chart1.Series["Default"].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineColor = Color.Red;
chart1.Series["Default"].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineWidth = 2;
chart1.Series["Default"].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutStyle = LabelCalloutStyle.Box;
```

If that doesn't produce the effect you want, then your next option will be using custom labels

```
//IMPORTANT: For this event to work the event handler must be added to the InitializeComponent()
//  method. We recommend that you add the event using the Properties window in the IDE   
private void Chart1_Customize(System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart sender)
{
    // Get X and Y axis labels collections
    CustomLabelsCollection xAxisLabels = Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels;
    CustomLabelsCollection yAxisLabels = Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.CustomLabels;

    // Change text of the first Y axis label
    yAxisLabels[0].Text = "Zero";

    // Change Y axis labels
    for(int labelIndex = 1; labelIndex < yAxisLabels.Count; labelIndex++)
    {
        yAxisLabels[labelIndex].Text = yAxisLabels[labelIndex].Text + "�. 00'";
    }

    // Remove each second X axis label
    for(int labelIndex = 0; labelIndex < xAxisLabels.Count; labelIndex++)
    {
        // Adjust position of the previous label
        if(labelIndex > 0)
        {
            xAxisLabels[labelIndex - 1].ToPosition += 
                (xAxisLabels[labelIndex].ToPosition - xAxisLabels[labelIndex].FromPosition) / 2.0;
            xAxisLabels[labelIndex - 1].FromPosition -= 
                (xAxisLabels[labelIndex].ToPosition - xAxisLabels[labelIndex].FromPosition) / 2.0;
        }

        // Remove label
        xAxisLabels.RemoveAt(labelIndex);
    }
}
```

For more help with MS Chart, I strongly recommend that you download the working sample project [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61), it contains sample code on how to use the different parts of MS Chart, the code given here is from that sample project.